# YouTube feed API loads slow in FireFox

Tags: javascript, firefox, youtube

I have a webpage that pulls in a channel's upload feed and displays them. Everything works fine in chromium but as I said, in FireFox it's all a lot slower or even crashing.

I don't even know where to begin finding the problem with this, the site's live so you can check it out here http://lartmagazine.co.uk/lart-tv/.

To display the main large video I'm using:

```
    var gdata = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/LARTMagazine/uploads?alt=json&videoid?v=2&callback=?';
        $.getJSON(gdata, function(data) {
          var id = data.feed.entry[0].id.$t.split('/').reverse()[0];
          var htmlString = '<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/' + id + '?wmode=transparent&version=3&vq=hd1080&showinfo=0&modestbranding=1&autohide=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
          $('#loader').hide();
          $('#yTMain').append(htmlString); 
});//end load iframe
```

And then I'm using this to pull the thumbnails:

```
var ytapiurl    = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/LARTMagazine/uploads?alt=json&max-results=12&callback=?';
    $.getJSON(ytapiurl, function(data) {
      var list_data="";
      $.each(data.feed.entry, function(i, item) {
        var title    = item['title']['$t'];
        var thumbimg = item['media$group']['media$thumbnail'][0]['url'];
        var ytlink   = item['media$group']['media$player'][0]['url'];
        list_data   += '<div class="ytblock"><div class="videothumb"><a href="'+ ytlink +'"target="_blank">';
        list_data   += '<img src="'+thumbimg+'" /></div><div class="yttitle"><h2>'+ title + '</h2></div></a></div>';
    });//end gdata
```

Is there something that I'm doing wrong with my data request that's lagging in FireFox for some reason? Other than that I have no idea.

If you need more information just ask.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the option "html5=1" - I am using iframes, but the YouTube API replaces your div with an iframe, so that should be the same.

```
src="//www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEOID?autoplay=1&html5=1&enablejsapi=1
```